# The App Engine SDK root was not set. Please make sure you set the environment variable 'APPENGINE_HOME' system property 'appengine.sdk.root'!

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, gradle

Studio was not able to download appengine sdk on its own. Was giving -

> Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':DeviceLocatorBackend:appengineSdk'.
>   Could not download artifact 'appengine-java-sdk.zip (com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18)'
>   Failed to download resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.18/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18.zip'.
>   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 172104706; received: 79691776

So I disabled the downloading part and decided to set it up manually -

build.gradle -

```
dependencies {
    //appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
}

appengine {
    //downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

commented download settings and manually created gradle.properties file and added

```
systemProp.appengine.sdk.root=/Users/athakur/Dropbox/personal/DeviceLocatorProject/SDK/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42
```

I have also set the environment variable -

```
export APPENGINE_HOME=/Users/athakur/Dropbox/personal/DeviceLocatorProject/SDK/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42
```

Still it gives me following error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':DeviceLocatorBackend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
>   The App Engine SDK root was not set. Please make sure you set the environment variable 'APPENGINE_HOME' system property 'appengine.sdk.root'!

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you found a solution?